Is there a way to check which line or function threw the exception I caught?
I work with code which looks similar to:
try {
    f1();
    f2();
    f3();
}
catch(Exception) {
    //...
}

If in Visual Studio I set a breakpoint within the catch block, is there a way for me to find out which function in the try block threw the exception?
Removing the try block to see when the program crashes is not a viable option for me.
The type of the exception does not allow to make a guess easily.

Look at the stack trace

You can use the StackTrace proprty of the Exception:

A string that describes the immediate frames of the call stack. If no
stack trace is available (such as prior to stack unwinding from a
throw statement), the value is null.

This string will give you the stack of function calls leading to the exception, including the line number for each call. If you have multiple calls to the function throwing the exception, you can find out exactly which call triggered it from the line number.
This is demonstrated in the test below:
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void f1() {}

        static void f2() {}

        static void f3(int n) { if (n == 2) throw new Exception(); }  // line 11

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                f1();
                f2();
                f3(1);
                f3(2);   // line 20
                f3(3);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var st = e.StackTrace;
                Console.WriteLine(st);
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:
   at Test.Program.f3(Int32 n) in C:\<...>\Program.cs:line 11
   at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\<...>\Program.cs:line 20

As you can see, the call to f3 was originated in Main, line 20 (the call with n==2).
Note:
The output above was acquired from a Debug build. In Release build some information might be missing or inaccurate (due to optimizations etc.).

Ah, the line number is indeed present in StackTrace property, but when I was hovering it in Visual Studio, the popup was too wide for my screen, and the line number was truncated... Printing StackTrace, or even using "View" function in Visual Studio displays the whole contents.

Check the stack trace in the exception object.

Alright, this is already helpful, but StackTrace gives me only the name of the method which threw the exception. What if a method is called several times? Is there a way to distinguish them?

the stacktrace also gives you a line https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getfilelinenumber?view=net-8.0#system-diagnostics-stackframe-getfilelinenumber

Note that this won't work in release builds unless you generate PDB files and deploy them with the application. And the line numbers still might not be accurate if optimisations have been applied.
